# Set in a set notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm not sure how to clearly express this informally, but

$A$ is a set containing *cars*, and $B$ is a set containing *parts*. But it is also so that $A_1$'s $B$ set is not the same set as $A_2$'s $B$ set, etc.

I could also use the following example to explain what I mean; $A$ is set of *moms* and $B$ are sets of children that a specific mom in the $A$ set has. Lets say $A_1$ is 'Kari' and $A_2$ is 'Lisa', 'Kari' is the mother of 'Karl' & 'Tia', while 'Lisa' is the mother of 'Bill'. The $B$ set does not contain all the children regardless of mother, but each mother has her own $B$ set.

How can I state using something like this using *Set Notation* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that what you are talking about is a set-function. It is a function which takes an element from $A$, say a mother, and returns the set of children of the said mother.

One way to write it would be $\{B_a\mid  a\in A\text{ and } B_a\text{ is the set of children of }a \}$.

Comment: That seems very clear, thanks!

Comment: @Asaf, don't you just mean to _define_ $B_a$ to be the set of children of $a$?

Comment: @Trevor: Mean where?

Comment: @Asaf I'm just not sure what the set you wrote is supposed to be.  Is $a$ bound or free?

Comment: @Trevor: Ah, I see the problem now.

Comment: @Asaf I hope you don't mind that I wrote another answer in the meantime.

Comment: @Trevor: I don't own the site. Of course I don't mind! :-)

Comment: @Asaf That makes more sense, but it forgets which child set belongs to which mother (it's just the _range_ of the function.)

Comment: @Trevor: One could say that, but this is the same as saying that $\{A_\delta\mid\delta<\omega_1\}$ forgets which $\delta$ the $A$ came from. It's slightly sloppy, but everyone knows what does it mean when we say $A_\delta$, and in this case when we say that $a\in A$ and $b\in B_a$.

Comment: @Asaf That is a good point.  It just looked strange to me in this context.  If I dealt with sequences indexed by mothers more often then I probably would not bat an eye at it :)

Answer (score 2):

For every mother $a \in A$, you could define the notation $B_a$ to be the set of children of $a$—in symbols, $B_a = \{b : b \text{ is a child of } a\}$.

Or if you have enumerated the set $A$ of mothers as $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots\}$ then instead of writing $B_{a_i}$ for the children of the $i^\text{th}$ mother $a_i$, you could just write $B_i$ instead.  So $B_1$ denotes the set of children of $a_1$, and $B_2$ denotes the set of children of $a_2$, and more generally $B_i = \{b : b\text{ is a child of }a_i\}$.